# Insert record if email id and username not exist

Tags: c#, mysql

I have written this insert query:

```
INSERT INTO tblUsers(FirstName, LastName, UserName, Password
                     , EmailId, Created_Date, typeid) 
VALUES ('" + ObjUserProp.FirstName + "','" + ObjUserProp.LastName + "'
       ,'" + ObjUserProp.UserName + "','" + ObjUserProp.Password + "'
       ,'" + ObjUserProp.EmailId + "','" + ObjUserProp.Created_Date + "'
       ," + ObjUserProp.TypeId + ")
```

In that I need to check username and email is exist or not.If not exists then and only then insert  record other wise return false

Comment: [`INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) or [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) or [other methods](http://bogdan.org.ua/2007/10/18/mysql-insert-if-not-exists-syntax.html).

Comment: Dear drive by downvoter, if you must downvote, at least specify why. The question is clear, the DB design is dubious (storing unencrypted passwords with no salt). It has been asked a few times before (most likely), but in that case cast a close vote with the dup link.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tblUsers(FirstName, LastName, UserName, Password 
                     , EmailId, Created_Date, typeid)  
SELECT ObjUserProp.FirstName    as Firstname,    <<-- note the keyword SELECT
      ObjUserProp.LastName      as lastname,
      ObjUserProp.UserName      as username,
      ObjUserProp.Password      as password,
      ObjUserProp.EmailId       as emailid,
      ObjUserProp.Created_Date  as created_date,
      ObjUserProp.TypeId        as typeid
FROM DUAL 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM tbluser u 
  WHERE u.username = ObjUserProp.UserName 
    AND u.Emailid = ObjUserProp.EmailId) 
LIMIT 1
```

You'll have to put the quotes and `+`'s back into the query, but that's the general idea.

Comment: That won't insert anything if the user doesn't exists.

Comment: @CodeCaster Which is exactly what the OP asked for and exactly what I intended the code to do.

Comment: Well pardon my French, but isn't _"If not exists then and only then insert record"_ exactly the opposite of that?

Comment: I have written this:



INSERT INTO tblUsers(FirstName, LastName, UserName, Password, EmailId, Created_Date, typeid) VALUES ('" + ObjUserProp.FirstName + "','" + ObjUserProp.LastName + "','" + ObjUserProp.UserName + "','" + ObjUserProp.Password + "','" + ObjUserProp.EmailId + "','" + ObjUserProp.Created_Date + "'," + ObjUserProp.TypeId + ") WHERE NOT EXIST(SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE UserName='" + ObjUserProp.UserName + "' AND EmailId='" + ObjUserProp.EmailId + "')









Please tell me what wrong with it

Comment: @user985225 Read my answer, read your comment, look at the differences and then ask yourself about the nature of those differences.

Comment: @CodeCaster, yes parlez vous now I see qui eau contrare the other way round. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with two queries? First, use something like `select count(id) from users where username=<username> and/or email=<email>`, and if the count is 0 then do the insert.

Comment: What's wrong with that is that you're ping the DB-server twice for something that can easily be done in one query.

Comment: Define "easily". It's absolutely unclear for a quick reader what your wall of SQL does, while the two simple queries (one select and one insert) can't get any more clear. Furthermore, you most likely don't want to handle this in one query, for when the `select count` returns 1, you might want to display an error message of some kind. Yes, that can be achieved by requesting the number of affected rows after executing your query, but that seems more like a workaround to me than one extra query.

Comment: depends on how many inserts you are doing. And I don't lile pinging the DB without need. Esp if the client and server are not on one machine.

Answer (score 0):

While Microsoft SQL Server offers an `IF NOT EXIST` option for SQL statements, if you are using MYSQL I would recommend utalizing the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax.

This can be done in your example by doing the following:

```
INSERT INTO tblUsers(FirstName, LastName, UserName, Password
                 , EmailId, Created_Date, typeid) 
VALUES ('" + ObjUserProp.FirstName + "','" + ObjUserProp.LastName + "'
   ,'" + ObjUserProp.UserName + "','" + ObjUserProp.Password + "'
   ,'" + ObjUserProp.EmailId + "','" + ObjUserProp.Created_Date + "'
   ," + ObjUserProp.TypeId + ") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id
```

You will need to make sure that the emailId and UserName are set as KEYs in the table.